# Finding the orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm

Tags: matrices, inner-products, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I'm relatively new to inner product and I was asked to obtain an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ using

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}        
    1 \\                      
    1 \\                    
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}   ,  \begin{pmatrix}        
    1 \\                      
    0 \\                    
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}        
    0 \\                      
    1 \\                    
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

by applying the Gram Schmidt algorithm which I have found to be

$$
    (\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})\begin{pmatrix}         
    1 \\                      
    1 \\                    
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}   ,  (\frac{\sqrt 6}{2})\begin{pmatrix}        
    1/3 \\                      
   -2/3 \\                    
    1/3 \\
    \end{pmatrix} , (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})\begin{pmatrix}        
    -1 \\                      
    0 \\                    
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

In addition to that my inner product was defined to be $\langle u,w\rangle = u_1w_1+ 2u_2w_2+ 3u_3w_3 $.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the defined innerproduct as such. What do i have to do to solve this question or have i gotten the concept all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the inner product that you were given. With respect to *that* inner product, $\|(1,1,1)\|=\sqrt6$ and therefore the first vector that you get when you apply Gramm-Schmidt is $e_1=\frac1{\sqrt6}(1,1,1)$. Then, let$$a_2=(1,0,1)-\langle(1,0,1),e_1\rangle e_1=\left(\frac13,-\frac23,\frac13\right).$$It norm is $\sqrt{\frac43}$ and so you take $e_2=\frac1{2\sqrt3}(1,-2,1)$. Finally, you take$$a_3=(0,1,2)-\langle(0,1,2),e_1\rangle e_1+\langle(0,1,2),e_2\rangle e_2=\left(-\frac32,0,\frac12\right).$$Its norm is $\sqrt3$ and so you take $e_3=\frac1{\sqrt3}\left(-\frac32,0,\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the inner product is an abstract concept. Check out the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) article. You can use the GS process with any inner product, just use your inner product definition to calculate $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ where it appears!

Answer (score 0):

Which inner product did you use for your orthogonal projections during Gram-Schmidt ? Make sur you stay consistent with using the same inner product all the time. Recall : the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto $v$ is given by $\text{proj}_vu=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle v,v \rangle}v$, and the norm of a vector $w$ as defined is this context is equal to $||w||=\sqrt{\langle w,w \rangle}$